# Pipeable operator rxjs and Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have such effect:

```
@Effect()
  updateMappingAfterChangeFieldType$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(EditableObjectSchemaActionTypes.EditFieldType),
    withLatestFrom(
      this.store.select(fromReducers.getMappingFields),
      this.store.select(fromCore.getTimezones) // **
    ),
    map(([action, mappingFields, timezones]: [EditFieldType, MappingModel[], Timezone[]]) => 
    {
      const { uuid } = action.payload;
      const { fieldType } = action.payload;
      const fieldForUpdate = mappingFields.find(field => field.uuid === uuid);
      const defaultTimezone = timezones.find((timezone) => timezone.isDefault);// **
      const timezoneId = fieldType === DATE_TYPE ? defaultTimezone.id : '';// **
      return new UpdateExistingMapping({
        ...fieldForUpdate,
        timezoneId
      });
    })
  );
```

Lines marked with `//**` used in many places. I want to make it pipeable operator. So it will look something like this:

```
@Effect()
  updateMappingAfterChangeFieldType$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(EditableObjectSchemaActionTypes.EditFieldType),
    withLatestFrom(
      this.store.select(fromReducers.getMappingFields)
    ),
    getDefaultTimezoneId,
    map(([action, mappingFields, defaultTimezoneId]: [EditFieldType, MappingModel[], string]) => 
    {
      const { uuid } = action.payload;
      const { fieldType } = action.payload;
      const fieldForUpdate = mappingFields.find(field => field.uuid === uuid);
      return new UpdateExistingMapping({
        ...fieldForUpdate,
        timezoneId: defaultTimezoneId
      });
    })
  );
```

How i can do this? By the way effect is in the class. How can i import `pipe`? Because when i tried `import {pipe} from 'rxjs/Rx'` i am getting an error about blacklist

Comment: You don't import pipe, you call it on an observable.

Comment: As for making you own operator, you should look at existing implementations and show us what you tried

Comment: there is no need; it comes free with observable :-)

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md#build-your-own-operators-easily